# Почему возникает ошибка: "PLS-00302: component must be declared", хотя указанное там имя существует?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Создаю свой тип данных:

```
create or replace type sh.itemobj is object (id int, memo varchar2 (64))
/
Type ITEMOBJ compiled

select sh.itemobj (1, 'memo') item from dual;

ITEM(ID, MEMO)
---------------------
ITEMOBJ(1, 'memo')
```

Никаких ошибок нет и можно им воспользоваться в запросе, но когда пробую в PL/SQL блоке:

```
declare 
    ret sh.itemobj;
begin 
    ret := sh.itemobj (1, 'memo');
end;
/
```

То получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:
PLS-00302: component 'ITEMOBJ' must be declared
```

Почему эта ошибка, как её избежать?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/28706077

Answer (score 2):

Причина ошибки довольна проста:

> component 'ITEMOBJ' must be declared

В сообщении об ошибке не упоминается имя схемы. То есть, при разрешении полного имени был найден объект БД с именем `SH`, совпадающий с именем схемы. Далее, для найденного объекта `SH` идёт безуспешный поиск компонента с именем `ITEMOBJ`. [Как идёт разрешение имён в  PL/SQL и его различиях с SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-848E544F-7C7A-41F6-BFDC-BBEC58DC6F24).

Найти такие объекты можно следующим запросом:

```
select object_name, object_type 
from user_objects where object_name=upper('sh')
/

OBJECT_NAME  OBJECT_TYPE 
------------ ------------
SH           SEQUENCE
```

Тут единственное решение, или переименовать объект БД, или удалить его:

```
drop sequence sh
/
Sequence SH dropped.

declare 
    ret sh.itemobj;
begin 
    ret := sh.itemobj (1, 'memo');
end;
/ 
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```